# Hide poles circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to draw an amplifier (not an op amp, just an amp) in circuitikz. What I did manage to do is the following picture/code

```
    \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
    \draw
       (0,0) node[fd op amp] (opamp) {}
       (opamp.+) to [short, -o] ++(-2,0)
       (opamp.-) to [short, -o] ++(-2,0)
       (opamp.out +) to [short, -o] ++(2,0)
       (opamp.out -) to [short, -o] ++ (2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
```

but I'd like to hide the poles in it. Is that possible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround: set the color of the symbols to white.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\ctikzset{tripoles/op amp/font= \fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\boldmath\color{white}}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
    \draw
       (0,0) node[fd op amp] (opamp) {}
       (opamp.+) to [short, -o] ++(-2,0)
       (opamp.-) to [short, -o] ++(-2,0)
       (opamp.out +) to [short, -o] ++(2,0)
       (opamp.out -) to [short, -o] ++ (2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I was trying out the command `\ctikzset{amplifiers/plus={}}
 \ctikzset{amplifiers/minus={}}` from page 91 of the manual but could not get it to work --how to go about using this command to get null values

Comment: @jsbibra - Try `\ctikzset{amplifiers/plus=\empty, amplifiers/minus=\empty}`  \null, \space and \strut also work.

Comment: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/circuitikz/amplifiers/pluspelled it. ...iers/plus=\empty, amplifiers/minus=\empty} why is the compiler telling me this? It happens every time I try to edit amplifiers options

Comment: @frad maybe you have an older version of `circuitikz`? The `amplifiers/plus` and `/minus` options are a relatively recent addition. Anyway, the workaround in my answer should work for older versions as well, although it is not so 'clean' as setting the plus and minus sign explicitly.